# Android TCP communication with C# Server -> socket.Close

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, tcp

I have an Android client and a C# server. They are communicating over sockets and the C# server handles receiving asynchronously.

The communication itself works with no problems. I can authenticate the client on the server and send messages to each other. But if I try to close the socket on the client via

```
socket.close();
```

the server gets "spammed" with empty packets. This happens as soon as the OutputStream gets closed.

This is my Android Client Code:

```
public void run()
{ 
    try
    {                   
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(pServerIp);            
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, pServerPort);
        try 
        {
            OutputStream socketoutstr = socket.getOutputStream(); 
            OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter( socketoutstr ); 
            bw = new BufferedWriter( osr ); 

            InputStream socketinstr = socket.getInputStream(); 
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( socketinstr ); 
            br = new BufferedReader( isr );                      

            User tmp = Login("SESAM", "PASSWORD");
            if(tmp != null)
            {
                Log.e("TCP", "Login succeeded!");
                user = tmp;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("TCP", "Login failed!");
                socket.close();
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            socket.close();
        } 
        finally 
        {
        }
    } 
}
```

This is the part of my server code which handles incoming data:

```
private void WaitForData()
{
    try
    {
        WorkerCallback = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);

        UndefinedPacket packet = new UndefinedPacket();
        socket.BeginReceive(packet.DataBuffer, 0, packet.DataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, WorkerCallback, packet);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
    }
}

private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
{
    UndefinedPacket socketData = (UndefinedPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        int CharCount = socket.EndReceive(asyn);
        char[] chars = new char[CharCount];

        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        String text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(socketData.DataBuffer);
        int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.DataBuffer, 0, CharCount, chars, 0);

        String data = new String(chars);
        if (data.Length > 0)
        {
            IClientPacket packet = PacketFactory.GetInstance(data);
            server.PacketManager.AddIncomingPacket(packet, this);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Received Data!");
        WaitForData();
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnDataReceived: Socket has been closed");
        server.RemoveWorkerSocket(this);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        if (se.ErrorCode == 10054) // Connection reset by peer
        {
            string msg = "Client Disconnected";
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            server.RemoveWorkerSocket(this);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
            server.RemoveWorkerSocket(this);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        server.RemoveWorkerSocket(this);
    }            
}
```

When I simply close the Android emulator I get the correct server message: "Client Disconnected".

But when I close the Outputstream or the whole socket on client-side OnDataReceived() gets called repeatedly very fast with a data.length of '0'.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you able to try with a real device just to rule out the emulator from the list of possible causes?

Comment: also try closing the input and output streams as well before closing the socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not empty "packets" (mind you TCP is a *stream*) - reading zero bytes from TCP socket means the other end closed the connection, so you should close your end too.

"client disconnected" here is probably the result of an [RST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) from the emulator when it goes down and cutting all connections.

Comment: Ok but why does 'OnDataReceived' gets called if there is no data sent?

Comment: Exactly to tell you that you have to close the connection.